# ansi C fprintf("File_Name","a") puts last printed string at the top of the file

Tags: c

I have been instructed to write a code to will perform a function and then call another function to print the results to a file. I used the "a" operator because the print function is called multiple times.

Whenever I run the function using printf, everything prints to the console perfectly. When I use fprintf, the last this to be printed ends up on the beginning of the text file.

Any idea why this may be happening and what I could do to fix it?

Code for my print function is below:

```
void WriteNos(int Case, int dec, long float Float) {
    Output = fopen("cp2.out", "a"); /*initialize output file ins append mode so that file is not over written at every call function*/
    int j; /* initialize j counter for printing Float to dec*/
    switch (Case)
    {
    case 1:/* called from  ConvertDecInt2binary */
    {fprintf(Output,"The binary representation of decimal \t \t %d is %s\n", dec, DectoBinarray); } /*dec in this case is the decimal integer used for ConvertDecInt2binary. DectoBinarray is a global array*/
        return;
    case 2: /*Called from ConverBinary2Dec*/
    {fprintf(Output,"The decimal representation of binary \t%s is\t%d\n", BinarrayPrint, dec); }/*dec in this case is a decimal integer calculated in ConvertBinary2Decimal, BinarrayPrint is a global array*/
        return;

    case 3:/*Called from ConvertFloatInt2Binary*/
    {  fprintf(Output, "The binary representation of decimal \t \t%.6lf is %c ", Float, FloattoBinary[0]); /*Float is the Flot point number used in converDecFloat2binarynFloatBinary is a global array whole 0 location is the sign bit*/
            for (j = 1; j <= 8; j++)
            {
                fprintf(Output,"%c", FloattoBinary[j]); /*print the exponant in binary form*/
            }
            fprintf(Output, " ");
            for (j = 31; j >= 9; j--)/*print the mantissa in binarry form*/
            {
                fprintf(Output,"%c", FloattoBinary[j]);
            }
            fprintf(Output,"\n"); /*Print a new line */
                return;
            }
        case 4:
        {
            fprintf( Output,"\n"); 
            return;
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Likely need to close the file at the end if the function.

Comment: Show us your full code. Which one is the "last" line that gets printed at the top? Also, as suggested in the above comment, close the file pointer `fclose(output);` and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: @VHS not the full code. An [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Use `fclose`before returning from function.
Also check return value of `fopen` every time.
Or I think `Output` is a global variable( No local declaration found). So no need to open and close every time.